# How to get multi keys event in Node.js terminal app?

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, stdin, keyboard-events

I'm trying to read the keyboard input in a Node.js terminal application.
Currently, I can only read 1 key each time with some code like this:

```js
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('data', console.log);
```

I can also read some special keys (i.e. ctrl, shift, alt) at the same time they are pressed with other keys. But it doesn't work for all the keys.

For example, I cannot read `w` and `d` at the same time they are pressed. Only one of them will be caught in that listener (the latest one).

So, any idea how I can read multiple keys at the same time? (even more than 2 keys)

It's also fine if you recommend me any library that does this thing, then I can check its code to see how it works.

Comment: Terminals are text-based. Imagine pressing two buttons at the same time in a text input, only the last one will repeat.

Comment: @Konrad So there is any way to get the events from terminal window? Or even just listening to `keyDown` and `keyUp` could help, I guess. But how? :)

Comment: The code will vary with each os and terminal emulator, but you can look at that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621382/capturing-global-keyboard-events-on-linux-with-nodejs
If terminals allowed doing stuff like that, there wouldn't be any window applications I guess